# how to reach a host on a different subnet

Tags: ip, subnet

I am new to networking and I am trying to work through a problem however I have become a bit stuck.

I have a network with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.128, I have connected the routers for each of the subnets with a serial DTE cable, each router has an ip of the other subnet.

Router 1

```
Fast Ethernet 0/0
IP: 222.240.10.1
Mask: 255.255.255.128

Serial 0/0
IP: 222.240.10.130
Mask: 255.255.255.128
```

Router 2

```
Fast Ethernet 0/0:
IP: 222.240.10.129
Mask: 255.255.255.128

Serial 0/0:
IP: 222.240.10.2
Mask: 255.255.255.128
```

My question is how can I get a host that is connected to router 1 to communicate with a host on router 2? if it is at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The serial interfaces on the routers need to belong to the same subnet. As it stands now, they don't.
2. You need to use a different subnet on the serial interfaces of the routers than the one you've supplied in your question. The 222.240.10.x subnets should be configured on the Ethernet interfaces only. You can use something like 10.0.0.1/8 and 10.0.0.2/8 on the serial interfaces on the routers.
3. Each router needs to have an appropriate routing table entry to reach the opposing Ethernet network.
4. Once you've done that you'll need to assign an ip address to your hosts in the appropriate subnet with the Ethernet ip address of the respective router as the Default Gateway.